# How to retrieve String value as a condition for if statment in java?

Tags: java, if-statement

I tried to do something like this but becasue getCondition will return me a string value the If statment throws error because it expect to have a boolean value.. is there is any way to retrieve and execute the String inside the if statment?

```
Private String condition = "age < 18";
String getCondition(){return this.condition;}

if(getCondition())
{....}
```

Comment: You would need to use some scripting engine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking here

[Is there an eval() function in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html